# AJAX: How to communicate to parent website

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hi I have a specific question concerning cross-website communication with ajax.
So imagine the following scenario: My web application consists of two  different parts. The first part consits of a header and a sidebar, lets call this one the parent. Inside of our parent page I implemented the other part using AJAX. For clarification I linked a screenshot below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipZTN.jpg[image]

The question is how can I submit data from the child ( 2nd part ) to the parent, i.e. change the content of the sidebar when submiting a button/form in the child. In addition to that I dont want the child page to reload/refresh.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Are there actually different frames, or just different regions of the page?

Comment: if they are using iframe you cant change the parent `IFRAME` content by calling from child `iframe`

Comment: Yes, since you are using the terms "parent" and "child" it seems you are using iframes. If you are using iframes, please don't. Restructure your site using only one HTML and update the content using JavaScript.

Comment: And you need to post your code; what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not using Iframes. The parent is based on a php script and the child is another php page that is displayed inside the parent webpage via AJAX. To be more precise: Is there a way  I can access the parent website content within the php script of the child

Comment: You cannot directly access *anything* on the client from within PHP code, because it's running on a separate device. You *can* access any part of the page from JavaScript however.